# How to separate list items by a string to save to a text file

Tags: c#, file, text, report

I'm creating a Windows Form application in C# to store details about Car Boot Sales, such as date, location, pitch cost, if they're for charity etc. One of the specifications is that there must be the capability to save some information to text files such as all the car boot sales save into the carbootsaleall.txt file and I also need a button to save all the charity & non-charity car boot sales to different text files.

I have written the code which save all the car boot sales into a text file but I'm not sure how to separate the other car boot sales depending if they're for charity or not to a different file.

This is the code I have between the button to save all the car boot sales:

```
        List<CarBootSale> carbootsales = carBootSaleList.ReturnList();
        textReportGenerator.GenerateAllReport(carbootsales, AppData.CARBOOTSALE);
        MessageBox.Show("All Car Boot Sales have been written to the report file: " + AppData.CARBOOTSALE);
```

This is the code I have in the TextReportGenerator class:

```
    public void GenerateAllReport<T>(List<T> aList, string filePath) where T : IDisplay
    {
        FileStream outFile;
        StreamWriter writer;

        outFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        writer = new StreamWriter(outFile);

        foreach (T obj in aList)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(obj.Display());
        }
        writer.Close();
        outFile.Close();
    }
```

Here is the CarBootSale class with the construtor etc:

```
public class CarBootSale : IDisplay
{

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public double PitchCost { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
    public string Charity { get; set; }
    public string CharityName { get; set; }
    public string Catering { get; set; }

    public CarBootSale(string id, string date, string location, double pitchcost, int capacity, string charity, string charityname, string catering)
    {
        ID = id;
        Date = date;
        Location = location;
        PitchCost = pitchcost;
        Capacity = capacity;
        Charity = charity;
        CharityName = charityname;
        Catering = catering;
    }
```

How would I be able to modify the button code and code in the TextReportGenerator class to also have the option to save charity car boot sales to carbootsalecharity.txt

Comment: how do you distinguish between those that are for charity and those that are not?

Comment: @vlad In the Charity string, it would either say yes or no in the windows form.

Comment: while I'm sure that that works, you may want to consider a `bool` for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Linq;

...

foreach (var obj in aList.Where(x -> x.Charity.ToLower() == "yes")
{
    writer.WriteLine(obj.Display());
}
```

If you need more generalization than this (i.e. you need it to work for any T), check out Predicate Builder or Dynamic Linq, or have T inherit a common interface containing Charity.

Comment: Hmmm, I seem to have 3 errors popping up saying "The name 'x' does not exist in the current context", "System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,bool>)' has some invalid arguments" and "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'System.Func<T,int,bool>'"

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's all pointing towards this part "aList.Where(x -> x.Charity.ToLower() == "yes"))"

Comment: If you're still trying to reference `Charity` against a type `T`, it won't work; it has to be of type `CarBootSale`, or you have to cast it to `CarBootSale`.